# selecting another dropdown option with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty selecting another dropdown option by option value="X" .. how can I do this?

```
<select id="type">
    <option value="all">All Types</option>
    <option value="1">Comments</option>
    <option value="2">Meanings</option>
    <option value="3">Thoughts</option>
</select>
```

It works if I do the code below, but because I usually put the total amount of types (so Comments 13, Meanings 6, etc) so the numbers are always changing from one form to another.

```
$("#type").val('Comments');
```

But how do I select it based on value="X" or value="all"

Comment: I don't know if I got this right, but you can get, for example, the 'Comments' option with this selector: `$("#type option[value=1]")`

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing option text with value

```
 $("#type").val(1);// will select option with text="Comments"
```

If you want to get the text and convert to selected

```
$('#type option').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text()=="Comments";

}).prop('selected',true)
```

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening.  When I do $("#type").val('all') the option (I guess behind the scenes?) does change since when I check the POST, it says all was selected.  However, the option text (comments, meanings, etc) does not change so the user still thinks they're on whatever they originally selected.

Comment: but what you are doing is forcing a value where that value doesn't exist in any option, so none gets selected to show user

Comment: so how would i force it to show 'All Types'?  My drop downs are alway different, so sometimes its All Types 500, All Types 343, All Types 0, etc.

Comment: if none of the other options text would contain "All Types" could use the contains() selector shown in other answers. I went for specific match due to unknowns and being absolute. Or could use match() in my mehtod insted of "=="

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#type option:contains("Comments")').prop('selected', true);
```

EDIT: After looking at this, if you use the following, you can pick based on value or option text: the following will both pick the second item in your list: with option value of 1 and text of Comments - with any suffex/other text in the Comments suchs as "Comments 33" still being supported.

```
var checkMe = '1';
$('#typePick option:contains("'+checkMe+'"), #typePick option:[value="'+checkMe+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

By Text:

```
 var checkMe = 'Comments';
 $('#typePick option:contains("'+checkMe+'"), #typePick option:[value="'+checkMe+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

And the distinct one: for `<option value="1">Comments 33</option>`

```
 var checkMe = 'Comments 33';
 $('#typePick option:contains("'+checkMe+'"), #typePick option:[value="'+checkMe+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

NOTE: the only difference in the last three examples is the value assigned to `checkMe`.

See here for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a7SQT/1/

Comment: hmm good options, thanks.  I'm having difficulty make it select the 'all' option.

Comment: @Mike See the example I posted which has one that selects the "All" option. (the "Click for All" button sets it)

Answer (score 0):

You're close--just call `val()` with the *value* of the option:

```
var value="2";
$("#type").val(value)
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/Fh22F/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/val/ always take/gives the data of the value attribute.

Try http://jsfiddle.net/rKMmg/

Comment: What about changing it on the fly?  So lets say the user changes it to 2 (meanings).  They then click on a submit button.  When this happens, I want the drop down to show all.  val('all') does it (because i can verify the POST) but the text in the drop down does not actually change to All Types

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value based off the text, you can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('#type option:contains(Comments)').val();
```

Otherwise, if you want to set the value you can use the same selector and set the selected property:

```
$('#type option:contains(Comments)').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: contains is dangerous..what if another option has similar text?

Comment: If that was a concern, then yes your solution would be more conclusive.